# GPG error: "do_plaintext: wrote X bytes but expected Y bytes"

Tags: gpg, process-substitution

I'm having trouble using `gpg` when I use the `<()` syntax for [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html).

Here is a minimal-working example of my problem:

```
$ gpg2 -c -o out.gpg <(head -c 73729 /dev/zero)

gpg: do_plaintext(): wrote 65537 bytes but expected 65536 bytes
```

When the input file is less than `73729` bytes, I don't get the error. (On my friend's computer the maximum filesize was `65535` bytes. I notice that 73729 is very close to 65535 + 2^13, not sure if that's relevant.)

However, it works when I use the pipe-based process substitution:

```
$ head -c 73729 /dev/zero | gpg2 -c -o out.gpg
```

**Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong with the `<()` syntax?**

[Here is the file in the GPG source code on GitHub](https://github.com/gpg/gnupg/blob/112e02ee89b78369c1c50e672873e726cbfeb994/g10/build-packet.c) where the error appears.

Here is my version of GPG:

```
$ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.5
libgcrypt 1.8.2
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: /Users/XXXXXXXX/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

Thanks for your help!